# passing function parameter names as strings

Tags: python

I'm working with an API that has dozens of parameters in a given function:

```
api.update_customer(a='', b='', c='', ..., x='', y='', z='')
```

I'll only need to update one or a few parameters when I call it, for instance:

```
api.update_customer(email='new.email@example.com')
```

...but I won't know in advance which object needs updating (maybe email, maybe phone number, etc).

How can I build a wrapper around this call so I can pass in both the parameter name and its new value?

```
def update_customer_details(key, value):
    api.update_customer(key=value)
```

Comment: search for python decorators. That's what you are looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to write a wrapper. Just pass a dict using keyword expansion.

```
params = {'email': 'new.email@example.com'}
api.update_customer(**params)
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Daniel Roseman answer for an example on how it gets used:

```
def test2(x=None):
    print(x)

def test(**kwarg):
    test2(**kwarg)

test(x=5)
```

output: `5`

Answer (score 0):

you can  try:

```
api.update_customer(field='my_field', value='my_value', *args, **kwrgs)
```